# How to ensure valid version of System.Web.Mvc is used

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My hosting provider has MVC 2 Preview 2 installed on server.

How to ensure my app uses MVC 2 Beta dll ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the .dll to a folder in your project, and reference it by browsing to it in the Add Reference dialog.  Make sure it gets uploaded with your project.

Using file references will always ensure you're referencing the assembly you want.  If you use GAC references, then the reference can change to some other assembly version unless you've specified to use a specific version.